# Authenticate with Ubuntu One (launchpad) account

Tags: ubuntu-one, authentication, launchpad, single-sign-on

I have a team on Launchpad and I want to let the members log in to some web apps on my server. How can I let users log in with Ubuntu SSO/OpenId and check if they are member of a specific group there?

Comment: Have you look at https://help.launchpad.net/API ?